# Regular expression multiline stop at a pattern

Tags: regex

I have this text

```
Owner's Name : John doe
State : New York
Country : US
Address : address line 1
address line 2
46000
Tel. No. (Off) : xxxx
```

I would like to use regular expression to capture

```
Address : address line 1
address line 2
46000
```

This stops at the `Tel line...`(doesn't capture).

Been trying to use lookahead but to no avail.

Comment: What language are you trying this in? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can't you encode the address and turn carriage returns into \n first or something? You could do this as a regex but it would become complicated and you'll never decipher when you look at it in a months time.

Comment: @David, in php or vbscript, whichever works:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
Address *: *([\s\S]*?)(?=Tel\. No\.)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oP4rH7/2)

Comment: Perhaps be safe and use `[\s\S]*?` in case there's more than one record per string.